# Visual Studio Go to Definition (F12) opens Object Browser instead of Code View

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2005

I'm running VS2005, and when I right click on an object and select Go to Definition it brings me to the object browser instead of the actual code.

Is there some settings that I can change to fix this?  Note: it works properly for C# solutions, I am having the problem with Basic.

Comment: It's now Visual Studio 2022, and I report that none of the 4 answers below resolve this issue for me.  My work around is to use Code Search instead of Goto Definition, and select what for me is often the second match (the first match being the object browser.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I usually see this when I have a reference to the library added as a "binary" reference rather than a "project" reference.  You might need to remove the reference and add it back from the projects tab.

Comment: your right, it's referenced to a dll.  Is this the only way to reference something in VB.NET that is written in C#?

Comment: You should be able to add both C# and VB.NET projects to a single soluion and should be able to access code from the VB project from the C# project and vice versa. You just can't mix C# and VB.NET in within a project.

Comment: You can't navigate in a single solution between vb.net and c# code using Visual Studio Go to Definition (F12), for that purpose you need something like resharper.

Comment: @ParthaChoudhury - After reading your comment I tried to do it myself - and I can confirm it did NOT work. Go to definition is not working between C# and VB.NET.

Answer (score 14):

This can also be caused by mismatched versions of the .Net framework in your advanced compile options.

[image: http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/bethmassi/WindowsLiveWriter/MigratinganOutlookClienttoVisualStudio20_CB9A/image_4.png]

I noticed that one of my projects was set as .net 3.5 and another was .net 4.0.

When I clicked `Go To Definition (f12)` on the .net 4.0 project, the code in the .net 3.5 project would only be shown in the object browser.

Luckily I am able to change both to be the same without any issues, but those with established code libraries may need to beware when changing the .net version.

Answer (score 3):

I saw this too while using Visual Studio 2015, in (C/C++) native projects, after switching between different git branches. The solution is to close VS, go in $(SolutionDir) and delete the .sdf file, then reopen the solution.

Comment: I had this issue with VS2015 Update 2 C/C++ native  projects as well. I followed your solution but did not have any .sdf file. Nevertheless I removed the .db file and ipch folder and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly why, but I had my Solution in Release mode when I was seeing this issue.  When I put the solution into Debug mode debugging/navigating worked properly.