# How to disable automatic opening of object browser?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to open the class code file instead of the object browser when I click on "go to definition"?

Answer (score 2):

Just right click on the file in solution explorer and hit view code.

UPDATE:

You might want to check out this question [Visual Studio Go to Definition (F12) opens Object Browser instead of Code View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150021/visual-studio-go-to-definition-f12-opens-object-browser-instead-of-code-view)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for replying but I would like to use the F12 key which stands for "go to definition".

Answer (score 1):

If you have added the source code as a part of your solution, this should happen automatically. The object browser seems to open instead when the source code of the class cannot be found by your project (say you've added a reference to the other project via dll only).

If the classes you want to open are Microsoft code you can [enable .NET framework source debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667410.aspx)

Comment: Hi Michael, I guess you and @elReyAlexis are both right. Unfortunately, I'm a .NET beginner, I don't know how to add the reference properly and my team mate is not available for now. I have to wait until next week. Thanks anyway.